# Echo datas from an array with php

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array in php:

```
$stats = array(
    "Item 1"    =>   20,
    "Item 2"    =>   30,
    "Item 3"    =>   66,
    "Item 4"    =>   1
);
```

I need to echo these values, so I try this:

```
<?
    foreach ($stats as $stat => $data) {
        echo '
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="widget">
                    <div class="widget-body p-t-lg">
                        <div class="clearfix m-b-md">
                            <h1 class="pull-left text-primary m-0 fw-500"><span class="counter" data-plugin="counterUp">'.$data.'</span></h1>
                            <div class="pull-right watermark"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-tv"></i></div>
                        </div>
                        <p class="m-b-0 text-muted">'.$stats[$stat].'</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        ';
    }
?>
```

But I have only the numerical values echoed.

Do you have the solution ?

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is the output you're expecting? And just fyi `$stats[$stat]` will print the same thing as just using `$data` inside the foreach loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using the `foreach` construct, `$stat` holds the keys and `$data` holds the values. So when saying  echo `$stats[$stat]` is equivalent to echoing the value that has the key `$stat`. If you want to echo the keys you should do this : `echo $stat`.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are trying to print the index of the array,

```
$array = array(0 => 'blue', 1 => 'red', 2 => 'green', 3 => 'red');
$key = array_search('green', $array); // $key = 2;
echo $key;
```

Use this code to print the key of the array